# do stuff after ajax is complete with angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

How do I do stuff after the ajax-call is done in with angular?

See this code:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myUrl + myData
}).
success(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
}).
error(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
});
alert("do not alert me before running doStuff()");
```

I want to run doStuff before the alert

Comment: What alert are you referring to?

Comment: sorry, It got lost. Now its back :)

Comment: Ah, I formatted your code a bit, but I think it overwrote your edit. Sorry about that. Can you just add it again?

Comment: Call the alert inside the callbacks of success and error before the call to `doStuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If doStuff is synchronous (blocking the next line until it returns):

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myUrl + myData
}).
success(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
    alert("do not alert me before running doStuff()");
}).
error(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
    alert("do not alert me before running doStuff()");
});
```

If doStuff is asynchronous (next line is executed before the function returns) you need to use a callback:

```
function doStuff(data, callback) {
   ...do the stuff here...
   callback(); // Run the callback
}

function myAlertFunc() {
     alert("do not alert me before running doStuff()");
}

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myUrl + myData
}).
success(function (data) {
    doStuff(data, myAlertFunc);
}).
error(function (data) {
    doStuff(data, myAlertFunc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use '**finally**':

```
http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myUrl + myData
}).
success(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
}).
error(function (data) {
    doStuff(data);
}).
finally(function(data){
    alert("do not alert me before running doStuff()");
});
```

However 'finally' is a reserved word in javascript and this will break on ie8, so a more compatible way to use it would be calling it with brackets notation like

```
http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myUrl + myData
}).
success(function(data){
    doStuff();
})
['finally'](function(data){
    doOtherStuff();
});

// note that there is no dot before ['finally']
```

Check out the official documentation on Promises Api in angular to learn more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: If doStuff is synchronous, and the alert should always be called, this is a better solution than mine.